# Introductory Topology

Tags: general-topology

$f, g:(\mathbb{R}, \tau_\mathbb{R}) \to (\mathbb{R}, \tau_\mathbb{R})$ are two continuous functions. Show that the set $\{x: f(x)\le g(x)\}$ is closed.

I'm not really sure where to start this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can show $\{ x : f > g \} $ is open set since this set is the complement of your given set, and we all know the basic fact that a set is open iff its complement is closed. Since $f$ and $g$ are continuous, then by basic calculus we know $h = f -g $ must be continuous. Take the open set $(0, \infty) $ (proof?) . Then, by definition of continuity, $h^{-1} ( (0, \infty ) ) = \{x : h > 0\} = \{ x : f - g > 0 \} = \{ x : f > g \}  $ must be open. The problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Consider the inverse image under $h$ of the appropriate closed set, where $h=g-f$.